# Image alignment issues

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a problem with a website I am developing right now, and I've been scratching my head here for a while. Basically I have a responsive design, however I want the images to all be centered together (with the yellow image directly above where the magenta image is currently) and then the 'block' of images to center horizontally and vertically within available space. The code is currently hosted at http://dorreen.webfactional.com

The problem is that the images are misaligned - the top images are spread out and the bottom images are clustered together. I'm not sure exactly what I should post - Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edfjc4w0/) (Except the fiddle sort of works how I want it to)

The code:

```css
#textContent { width: 49%; }
#imgContent { width: 49%; }
.content {
    float: left;
    padding: 0% 0.5%;
}
.content > img { margin: 0.5% auto; }
```

```html
<div class="content" id="imgContent">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x240/ff0000/000000" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x240/ffff00/000000" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x240/00ff00/000000" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240x240/ff00ff/000000" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Also, you should explain the results you expect vs. the results you're experiencing.

Comment: Hi @j08691, is that better? If not, what else do you suggest I add? Sorry for not being the clearest, I'm not exactly sure of all the rules here and I'm trying not to step on any toes.

Comment: Yup, that's better. No worries, no toes were stepped on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the `text-align: justify` of the image container aligning all but the last line. To a zeroth approximation, `text-align:left` (or `center`, I guess) should help you.

Comment: or simply remove the text-align property altogether.

Comment: @skube: I admittedly didn't check where the OP got his alignment from in the first place.

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks - no idea how I didn't see that!